Animated movie with a boy's toys coming to life
When I was younger, we had a lot of videotapes with movies. I recently remembered one, but I don't know the title and unfortunately we don't have the tapes anymore.
The movie was an animated movie. It was about a boy, and the time is around christmas. I think he was a poor orphan. There was some scene with a toy factory/store and maybe toys coming to life, but that last part I don't know for sure. I think there also was a girl involved somewhere, but I don't remember that exactly either. 
I watched the movie in dutch, but I don't think it was a dutch movie.
